# SELECT DISTINCT CLOB_COLUMN FROM TABLE;

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-00932

I would like to find the distinct CLOB values that can assume the column called CLOB_COLUMN (of type CLOB) contained in the table called COPIA.

I have selected a PROCEDURAL WAY to solve this problem, but I would prefer to give a simple SELECT as the following: SELECT DISTINCT CLOB_COLUMN FROM TABLE avoiding the error "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB"

How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance for your kind cooperation.  This is the procedural way I've thought:

```
-- Find the distinct CLOB values that can assume the column called CLOB_COLUMN (of type CLOB)
-- contained in the table called COPIA
-- Before the execution of the following PL/SQL script, the CLOB values (including duplicates) 
-- are contained in the source table, called S1
-- At the end of the excecution of the PL/SQL script, the distinct values of the column called CLOB_COLUMN
-- can be find in the target table called S2

BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE S1 DROP STORAGE';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE S1 CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      BEGIN
         NULL;
      END;
END;

BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE S2 DROP STORAGE';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE S2 CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      BEGIN
         NULL;
      END;
END;

CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE S1
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
AS
   SELECT CLOB_COLUMN FROM COPIA;

CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE S2
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
AS
   SELECT *
     FROM S1
    WHERE 3 = 9;

BEGIN
   DECLARE
      CONTEGGIO   NUMBER;

      CURSOR C1
      IS
         SELECT CLOB_COLUMN FROM S1;

      C1_REC      C1%ROWTYPE;
   BEGIN
      FOR C1_REC IN C1
      LOOP
         -- How many records, in S2 table, are equal to c1_rec.clob_column?
         SELECT COUNT (*)
           INTO CONTEGGIO
           FROM S2 BETA
          WHERE DBMS_LOB.
                 COMPARE (BETA.CLOB_COLUMN,
                          C1_REC.CLOB_COLUMN) = 0;

         -- If it does not exist, in S2, a record equal to c1_rec.clob_column, 
         -- insert c1_rec.clob_column in the table called S2
         IF CONTEGGIO = 0
         THEN
            BEGIN
               INSERT INTO S2
                    VALUES (C1_REC.CLOB_COLUMN);

               COMMIT;
            END;
         END IF;
      END LOOP;
   END;
END;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this approach. In table **profile** column **content** is NCLOB. I added the where clause to reduce the time it takes to run which is high,

```
with
  r as (select rownum i, content from profile where package = 'intl'),
  s as (select distinct (select min(i) from r where dbms_lob.compare(r.content, t.content) = 0) min_i from profile t where t.package = 'intl')
select (select content from r where r.i = s.min_i) content from s
;
```

It is not about to win any prizes for efficiency but should work.

Comment: With 100 records it works great, but with 5500 record it is too slow. Now I am trying to use ROWID instead of ROWNUM: ROWID is more efficient.

Comment: The problem will not be rownum vs rowid. The problem will be the O(n^2) or O(n^3) (just a guess) runtime characteristics.

Answer (score 14):

If it is acceptable to truncate your field to 32767 characters this works:

```
select distinct dbms_lob.substr(FIELD_CLOB,32767) from Table1
```

Comment: **If** truncation is tolerable, this solution is a lot more manageable than the accepted solution.

Answer (score 9):

You could compare the hashes of the CLOB to determine if they are different:

```
SELECT your_clob
  FROM your_table
 WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT MIN(ROWID) 
                   FROM your_table
                  GROUP BY dbms_crypto.HASH(your_clob, dbms_crypto.HASH_SH1))
```

---

#### Edit:

The `HASH` function doesn't guarantee that there will be no collision. By design however, it is really unlikely that you will get any collision. Still, if the collision risk (<2^80?) is not acceptable, you could improve the query by comparing (with `dbms_lob.compare`) the subset of rows that have the same hashes.

Comment: Interesting solutions, but my Oracle user has not access to DBMS_CRYPTO package.  How can I workaround?

Comment: Hashes are not guaranteed to be different for different inputs.

Comment: @Janek Bogucki: given the extremely low probability of a SHA1 hash collision, you can safely assume that two naturally occuring strings (i.e. not reversed engineered explicitely for this purpose) who have the same SHA1 hash are equal :)

Comment: Okay, but in Oracle PL/SQL is not available another package which implements the same functionality of DBMS_CRYPTO, that I can't see with my Oracle user?

Comment: I have thought to ORA_HASH, but is useless for my scope.

Comment: @The chicken in the kitchen: ask for the right to use this package ?

Comment: No, sorry, I am not authorized to ask the right to use DBMS_CRYPTO package :-(

Comment: I have tried with SYSMAN.ENCRYPT and SYSMAN.DECRYPT with no good results: I obtain the following error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "SYSMAN.ENCRYPT", line 10

Comment: Watch out for null arguments to dbms_crypto.HASH(x, 3). +1 for hash collision probability observation.

Comment: I am not authorized to use DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH: my Oracle user does not see this package.

Comment: You say: "this user needs to use DBMS_CRYPTO, otherwise your problem will not be solved." There are no real security risks with the grant. It's common practice to only grant privileges as required. Here, you have a case where it's required, so they should grant it.

Comment: Thanks for your kind explanation Jeffrey, but in my work environment the use of this native Oracle package is not allowed.  My request has been declined.

Comment: Perhaps if you can't get permission for the user to have access to the whole package, then maybe you can create a wrapper function under a more privileged user, and then the application's user can avoid using DBMS_CRYPTO directly.

Comment: How can I create a wrapper function similar to DBMS_CRYPTO??

Answer (score 9):

add `TO_CHAR` after distinct keyword to convert CLOB to CHAR

```
SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(CLOB_FIELD) from table1;   //This will return distinct values in CLOB_FIELD
```

Answer (score 3):

select distinct DBMS_LOB.substr(column_name, 3000) from table_name;

Answer (score 3):

If truncating the clob to the size of a varchar2 won't work, and you're worried about hash collisions, you can:

- Add a row number to every row;
- Use DBMS_lob.compare in a not exists subquery. Exclude duplicates (this means: compare = 0) with a higher rownum.

For example:

```
create table t (
  c1 clob
);

insert into t values ( 'xxx' );
insert into t values ( 'xxx' );
insert into t values ( 'yyy' );

commit;

with rws as (
   select row_number () over ( order by rowid ) rn,
          t.*
   from   t
)
  select c1 from rws r1
  where  not exists (
    select * from rws r2
    where  dbms_lob.compare ( r1.c1, r2.c1 ) = 0
    and    r1.rn > r2.rn
  );

C1    
xxx   
yyy
```

Answer (score 0):

To bypass the oracle error, you have to do something like this :

SELECT CLOB_COLUMN FROM TABLE COPIA C1
WHERE C1.ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT C2.ID FROM COPIA C2 WHERE ....)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I believe I've figure out a better way to do what you are asking.

It is kind of like a cheat really...The idea behind it is that You can't do a DISTINCT of a Clob column but you can do a DISTINCT on a Listagg function of a Clob_Column...you just need to play with the partition clause of the Listagg function to make sure it will only return one value.

With that in mind...here is my solution.

```
SELECT DISTINCT listagg(clob_column,'| ') within GROUP (ORDER BY unique_id) over (PARTITION BY unique_id) clob_column 
 FROM copia;
```